# Removing a line from a file using sed in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am currently working on a shell script where an error may sometimes get outputted to a file but I need the error moved as it doesn't mean anything and everything works as normal as long the error isn't there.

I have a script which has the following:

```
ftp ftp://$2:$3@$1 << BLOCK > $5
cd "$4"
ls
quit
BLOCK
```

$5 is the file that the output of the FTP command is written to. So in the file I have the following

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  42 Dec 17 14:26 test1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   6 Dec 17 14:08 test2.txt
```

Sometimes I get the error `?Invalid command.` so I am using `sed` to remove the error from the file. I have changed the shell script to the following. Note for testing I have put `error` within the FTP to ensure I get the error message mentioned above.

```
ftp ftp://$2:$3@$1 << BLOCK > $5
cd "$4"
ls
error
quit
BLOCK
fileout=$(sed '/?Invalid command./d' $5)
echo $fileout > $5
```

This is working in the sense that I am removing the error message but it also removing the line breaks so when I look at the file I get the following

```
total 8 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42 Dec 17 14:26 test1.txt -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Dec 17 14:08 test2.txt
```

How do I retain line breaks?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote `fileout` when you `echo` i.e. `echo "$fileout" > $5`, in order to preserve the line breaks.

BUT, instead of doing that, you should simply use `sed` to edit the file "in-place". Then you wouldn't have to save the output of `sed` into a variable and then `echo` it back out again, which is causing the issue.

Use:

```
sed -i '/?Invalid command./d' $5
```

instead of:

```
fileout=$(sed '/?Invalid command./d' $5)
echo $fileout > $5
```

Comment: Quoting the output of `sed` is absolutely absurd.  This is exactly what pipes are for.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
ftp ftp://$2:$3@$1 << BLOCK | sed ... > $5
...
BLOCK
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
ftp ftp://$2:$3@$1 << BLOCK | 
...
BLOCK
sed ... > $5
```